# Proving continuity using Urysohn's lemma

Tags: general-topology

> Suppose $X,Y$ are topological spaces such that $Y$ is $T_4$. Let $f:X
>  \to Y$ such that for all continuous functions $g:Y \to \mathbb R$ , $g
>  \circ f:X \to \mathbb R$ is continuous. Prove $f$ is continuous.

**My attempt:**
Let $A \subset Y$ be a non-trivial closed subset. $Y-A$ is an open non-empty subset of $Y$. So there exists $y \in Y-A$. $Y$ is $T_4$ so $\{y\}$ is closed in $Y$. Since $Y$ is normal there exists an open subset $V \subset Y$ such that $\{y\} \subset U \subset \overline U \subset Y-A$. Now, $\overline U $ and $A$ are disjoint, closed, non-empty subsets of $Y$, which is $T_4$ hence normal. By Urysohn's lemma
there exists $g: Y \to I=[0,1]$  such that $A \subset g^{-1}(\{0\}), \overline U \subset g^{-1}(\{1\})$. By assumption $g \circ f$ is continuous, and since $\{0\}$ is closed in $\mathbb R$, $(g \circ f)^{-1}(\{0\})=(f^{-1}\circ g^{-1})(\{0\})=f^{-1}(g^{-1}(\{0\})) \subset f^{-1}(A)$ is closed. But it's not enough in order to show that $f^{-1}(A)$ is closed. Am I in the right direction? Would appreciate any help.

Comment: Shouldn't $Y$ be assumed to be perfectly normal? To get equalities on preimages.

Comment: If $Y$ is perfectly normal then we indeed get eqaulities on preimages, but in this case it is not assumed it is perfectly normal.

Answer (score 1):

It suffices to assume that $Y$ is [completely regular](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tychonoff_space). This means that for each closed $A \subset Y$ and each $y \in Y \setminus A$ there exists a continuous $g : Y \to \mathbb R$ such that $g(y) = 1$ and $g \mid_ A = 0$.

Now assume that $f : X \to Y$ is not continuous. Then there exists a closed $A \subset Y$ such that $f^{-1}(A)$ is not closed in $X$. Pick $x \in \overline{f^{-1}(A)} \setminus f^{-1}(A)$. Then $y = f(x) \notin A$ since $x \notin f^{-1}(A)$. Choose a continuous $g : Y \to \mathbb R$ such that $g(y) = 1$ and $g \mid_ A = 0$. Then $g \circ f$ is not continuous because otherwise we would get
$$1 = g(y) = (g \circ f)(x))\in (g \circ f)\left(\overline{f^{-1}(A)}\right) \subset \overline{(g \circ f)(f^{-1}(A))} \\= \overline{g(f(f^{-1}(A)))}  \subset \overline{g(A)} = \overline{\{0\}} =  \{0\} .$$